# SQL Query against EXCEL Spreedsheet containing formulas

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am writing a component in C# which returns data from an EXCEl spreadsheet using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.  The spreadsheet contains cells with formulas and references to other spreadsheets within that workbook.  These cells return no data to the DataTable.  See example below.

```
OleDbConnection OleDBconn = new   OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"",InputFile));
OleDbCommand OleCommand = new OleDbCommand();
OleCommand.Connection = OleDBconn;
OleDBconn.Open();
dtXLS = OleDBconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleCommand);
OleCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT [Column] From [Sheet1$]");
adp.SelectCommand = OleCommand;
adp.Fill(dt);
```

Column contains cells with formulas and references to other worksheets in the workbook. So dt[0][Column] is null when it should have a value.  The cell in the spreadsheet contains the below reference

=dd!B2

Comment: Any solution so far? I am experiencing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

here is something that you can try in regards to filling and returning the DataTable

```
//call the method this way
var someDataTable = ExecuteDataSet("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", InputFile);


public static DataTable ExecuteDataSet(string sql, string InputFile)
{
    using (DataSet myDataset = new DataSet())
    using (OleDbConnection OleDBconn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"",InputFile));
    using (OleDbCommand cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(sql, OleDBconn))
    {
        try
        {
            OleDBconn.Open();
            dtXLS = OleDBconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);//if you need to return this change the method signature to out param for this
            new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSelect).Fill(myDataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Show a message or log a message on ex.Message
        }
        return myDataset.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like cmdSelect.Open();  should be OleDBconn.Open();.  Otherwise I tried it and I am getting the same results.

Comment: are you getting any errors can you provide more relevant information

Comment: No errors just that the data table returns {} in the immediate window when I return data for a cell which contained a cell reference or Formula.dTable.Rows[1][5]
{}

Comment: if you look at this value in the `QuickWatch myDataset.Tables[0]` and hit the little magnifying glass, does it show that the datatable has Rows of data..?

Comment: Yes we do have rows of data.  the exact number of rows in the sheet.  Just wondering if the SQL query has functions that I can use to force the cells to retrieve the referenced data or execute the formulas.

Comment: I see that some of the cells have data  but many are blank.  Could this be a time out issue?

Comment: I moved the primary worksheet to be the first in the work book and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem glad you I was able to provide some bit of help